# A default element outside ng-show

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I've been wondering if it's possible to have a default element outside of ng-show event, I wish these codes will explain what I meant.

```
<th>
    <a href="#" ng-click="orderByField='date'; reverseSortDate = !reverseSortDate">
      Date Created
      <span ng-show="orderByField == 'date'">
          <span ng-show="!reverseSort">
            <i class="icon-arrow-up active"></i>
            &nbsp;<i class="icon-arrow-down"></i>
          </span>
          <span ng-show="reverseSort">
            <i class="icon-arrow-up"></i>
            &nbsp;<i class="icon-arrow-down active"></i>
          </span>
      </span>
    </a>
</th>
<th>
    <a href="#" ng-click="orderByField='mobile'; reverseSortMobile = !reverseSortMobile">
      Mobile
      <span ng-show="orderByField == 'mobile'">
          <span ng-show="!reverseSortMobile">
            <i class="icon-arrow-up active"></i>
            &nbsp;<i class="icon-arrow-down"></i>
          </span>
          <span ng-show="reverseSortMobile">
            <i class="icon-arrow-up"></i>
            &nbsp;<i class="icon-arrow-down active"></i>
          </span>
      </span>
    </a>
</th>
```

I want to create a table which has an arrow (up and down) indicating the `orderBy` direction(ascending or descending). It works as a charm by using the code above, but I want to create a default arrow (before it tells which way it ordered) which doesnt have any `active` style, that will appear before `ng-click` trigger, dissapear when `ng-click` trigger (which will be replaced with `ng-show`). and re-appear when the other `th` got clicked (replaced the ng-show active th class).

This is default: Arrow △▽

This is active: Arrow **△**▽ and Arrow △**▽**

Let's assume bold carets are arrows with active class.

Comment: Note that it would make more sense to include the two arrows once in your markup and apply the active class as needed with ng-class, rather than have two separate sets of arrows with the class hard-coded.

Comment: Yes.. So I dont need ng-show and just use ng-class? I'm very new to angular,..